# Is there an NP problem that is not NP-complete or P?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, complexity-theory, np, np-complete

I am trying to understand the relationships between P, NP, NP-Complete and NP-Hard.

I believe I am starting to understand the general idea but, I am hung up on this question(see title).

What is an example of a problem that is *not* solvable in P time, is verifiable in P time but is *not* NP-Complete?

If there is some piece of understanding I am missing please fill me in.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should ask this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/are-there-np-problems-not-in-p-and-not-np-complete

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the question

Comment: Of course that there are many such problems. Unfortunately we do not know them and we cannot prove that they exist.

Comment: @Karol: Indeed! But let's not get depressed about that; instead let's remember what the fundamental question is:  **could one kind of impossible computing machine be used to solve problems that are definitely solvable by an even more impossible computing machine?** :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is the wrong site for this question. However, it can be answered briefly:

> What is an example of a problem that is not solvable in P time, is verifiable in P time but is not NP-Complete?

If I understand you, what you want are problems that are (1) not in P, (2) in NP, and (3) not in NPC. Such problems are the NP-intermediate (NPI) problems.

It is not known if there is any such problem, because it is not known if P=NP.

If P=NP then clearly there are no such problems; if P=NP then also P=NPC, and therefore every problem which can be verified in P time is in all of P, NP and NPC because they are equal.

If P!=NP then it is known that there *are* such problems; at least one exists.  Unfortunately we do not know if any real-world problems we face are in NPI provided that P!=NP. A list of likely candidates can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate

In short: *knowing whether NPI is empty or not is equivalent to solving proving P!=NP*, so get cracking! If you can find a problem that is definitely in NP but definitely not in P or NPC, then there's a big money prize awaiting you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and explained well.  Thanks!